# why using a generator in tornado.gen?

Tags: python, generator, tornado

Sorry for this dumb question, i want to understand the reason behind using a generator to replace a callback in tornado, how a generator can be useful in non blocking operation?

I thought a generator is only useful when returning a lot of items, so to save memory, we avoid iterators and generate one element by one, so where is the benefits in non blocking calls if there is only one element to return (example an http response)?

if i've this simple example:

```
class GenAsyncHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
@tornado.web.asynchronous
@tornado.gen.engine
def get(self):
    http_client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
    response = yield tornado.gen.Task(http_client.fetch, "http://www.google.fr")
    self.write(str(response))
    self.finish()
```

the result is:

```
HTTPResponse(code=200,request_time=0.4440000057220459,buffer=<_io.BytesIO object at 0x000000000316A728>,_body=None,time_info={},request=,effective_url='http://www.google.fr',headers={'X-Xss-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'Set-Cookie': 'PREF=ID=6e27eda171946585:FF=0:TM=1361200384:LM=1361200384:S=7VncGsz1u8j_UL1a; expires=Wed, 18-Feb-2015 15:13:04 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.fr,NID=67=qv6MUCQCGJ5mnofKWdySxo8NoThLfCr9oFlme8S95w2CNqQe__tW6ql3RzqItvfbFxzxCYLZ0OINzFvE7mIDJbXOjjhld0ahQrxfzizkdNhymcI9oAGK0dotqDHwhtR2; expires=Tue, 20-Aug-2013 15:13:04 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.fr; HttpOnly', 'Expires': '-1', 'Server': 'gws', 'Connection': 'close', 'Cache-Control': 'private, max-age=0', 'Date': 'Mon, 18 Feb 2013 15:13:04 GMT', 'P3p': 'CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN'},error=None)
```

does this result is splited to 'pause'?

Answer (score 1):

No your results is not because it will be sent only when you call flush.

With a generator you don't need to create another function for example if you have a form and then want to save it asynchronously in your db, you don't need to pass it around to render it in your view.

```
@web.asynchronous
@gen.engine
def post(self):
    form = inscription.Particulier(TornadoDict(self))
    form.application = self.application
    if form.validate():
        password = passwords.encode(self.get_argument('password'),
                                   self.get_argument('email'))
        values = (self.get_argument('email'),
                  password,
                  self.get_argument('nom'),
                  self.get_argument('prenom'),
                  self.get_argument('adresse'),
                  self.get_argument('ville'),
                  self.get_argument('telephone'),
                  self.request.remote_ip,)
        cursor = yield momoko.Op(self.db.execute,
                    sql.INSERT_PROFILE_PARTICULIER,
                    (values))
        result = cursor.fetchone()[0]
        if result[0] == 'ok':
            form[result[0]].errors.append(result[1])
            self.render('inscription/particulier.html', form=form)
        else:
            self.redirect('/app')
    else:
        self.render('inscription/particulier.html', form=form)
```

Comment: ah, now i see the utility, so in the example in tornado doc where response = yield gen.Task(http_client.fetch, "http://example.com") this means that the response is split too?

Comment: yeah basically gen allow the same things as async but in the same scope.

Comment: sorry i dont get the point? for example in the example you give, it saves the first then waits, else continue the operation until someelse requests the server, but what about a long 'bloc' of data (the HTTP response for example)

Comment: I m not sure I understand your question, but if you want to stream a big amount of data you can yield in a loop. And when you yield, your processor if free to handle other requests.